# How To Position Items Around A Cirlcle

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I found something like [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-roundrr/)

> A lot of the math that goes into basic shape-based positioning is relatively straight-forward. Chances are you probably already covered it in highschool, so much of this will seem familiar. Consider that a circle has a center (j,k) and a radius r. The x and y positions for any point that occurs on the circle’s path is then
>
> x(t) = r cos (t) + j, y(t)  = r sin(t) + k. A more generic way of writing this which can be used for our first attempt at coordinate-based positioning is:
>   ?
>   1
>   2
>
> x = centerX + Math.cos(radians) * radius;
>   y = centerY + Math.sin(radians) * radius;
>
> where radians =  (angle_of_the_circle/180) * Math.PI. centerX is the X center of the circle on our page and centerY is the Y center of the circle.

Could anyone please make my concept clear about above techniques that how does it work?

Comment: I couldn't understand properly.

Comment: Which part exactly is unclear?

Comment: each part of the math.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258009/how-to-position-items-around-a-cirlcle See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eGhPg/

Comment: Explaining trigonometry isn't exactly in SO's scope, or possible in a single answer. I suggest you pick up a trigonometry textbook.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11579813/405017 with demos http://jsfiddle.net/3MPrT/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/3MPrT/2/ http://jsfiddle.net/3MPrT/7/

Comment: @Juhana No! I know the trigonometry but here x(t).... n something I couldn't understand.

Comment: Then why did you say "each part of the math" was unclear? Those are basic trigonometric functions. What *exactly* is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @Phrogz How does this question reffers to duplicate question. this question is about math function to circle image.

Comment: @Juhana I mean to say here from x(t).... which is confusing me to understand so it is unclearing me all part.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but just in case: x(t) = r cos(t) + j is called functional notation in math. It basically means that whatever you plug in for t will equal x, so x(3.14) = r cos(3.14) = x.  Is that what was unclear @C-Link ?

Comment: @asifrc yes! something like that.

Comment: I wrote up an example of what you are doing that you can feel free to play around with.  Change the number of `<li>`s, change the offsets, radius, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/, or http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/1/ for more `<li>`s and a different radius and offset.

Comment: Here is another example, built from the first, with some animation on top: http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/6/, and another that uses some randomness as well: http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/7/

Comment: @sberry last one is very great

Comment: @C-Link Sorry, must have had the wrong link on my clipboard. I meant to say "Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889796/how-to-arrange-the-elements-of-a-semicircle-in-css-html-js"

Answer (score 5):

Since you seemed to like my example posted in the comment, I thought I would post it as an answer so it can live on forever in the answer section.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var radius = 100;
    var xCenter = 120;
    var yCenter = 120;
    var cnt = $('li').length;
    var angle = 0;
    var angleDelta = 2 * Math.PI / cnt;
    $('li').each(function(i, el) {
        x = radius * Math.cos(angle) + xCenter;
        y = radius * Math.sin(angle) + yCenter;
        $(this).css({top: y, left: x});
        angle += angleDelta;

    })
})
```

And some of the fiddles based on this
[jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8) A simple start
[jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/1](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/1) A larger example - just modifying radius, number of `<li>`s and offset values for the center.
[jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/6](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/6) Adding `<li>`s during runtime
[jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/7](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/7) Some randomness when adding the new elements.
[jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z7a8/8/) And for fun, one with some color changing (not perfect)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 more times